# Interior point method for unconstrained problems

Tags: functions, mathematical-optimization, implementation-details

I was recently working on applying the FindMinimum function to $f(x)=(x+1)(x-1)$, and chose the interior point method as the 'method', which yielded $x=0$. I would like to better understand how the interior point method works (is implemented) in this unconstrained case. Thanks!

The command and the result are indicated below:

```
FindMinimum[(x + 1) (x - 1), x, Method -> "InteriorPoint"]
```

[image: Interior point method for an unconstrained problem]

Comment: Look e.g. at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior-point_method

Comment: Interior to what?

Comment: Hello Daniel, thanks for your reply. My question above has been edited for clarity.

Comment: I cannot say for sure but possibly the non-default `Method` setting is just being ignored in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Not a complete answer, but one can get some idea of what is going on behind the scenes by keeping track of the values at which the function is evaluated:

```
f[x_?NumericQ]:=(Sow[x];(x+1)*(x-1));
Reap[FindMinimum[f[x],x,Method->"InteriorPoint"]]
```

The output tells us that the function was evaluated at

```
0.9999939445455476
1.0000060554544523
-4.000024221798069
-3.99997577816245
-4.000024221798069
-3.99997577816245
-4.000024221798069
-3.99997577816245, 
-4.000488281230257
-3.9995117187302616
-4.000464056455683
-3.9994874998692174, 
-3.9999999999802593
-9.247662058342598*^-8
-6.147931072976769*^-6
5.962977831809917*^-6
-0.00012216278912058343
0.00012197783587941657
-0.00011610733466819008 
0.00012803329033180992
-9.247662058342598*^-8
```

This changes when another `Method` is used.

**Alternative syntax.** This gives the same result as above:

```
f[x_?NumericQ]:=(x+1)*(x-1);
Reap[FindMinimum[f[x],x,Method->"InteriorPoint",
                 EvaluationMonitor:>Sow[x]]]
```

This gives a different result:

```
Reap[FindMinimum[(x+1)*(x-1),x,Method->"InteriorPoint",
                 EvaluationMonitor:>Sow[x]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

The code may be inspected with `` GeneralUtilities`PrintDefintions ``. The principal components of the method are the 1st, 2nd, and 4th functions here:

```
Names["*`*IPSolve*"]
(*
{"Optimization`NonlinearInteriorPointDump`IPSolve", \
"Optimization`NonlinearInteriorPointDump`IPSolveInternal", \
"Optimization`NonlinearInteriorPointDump`IPSolveMessage", \
"Optimization`NonlinearInteriorPointDump`IPSolveOneIter"}
*)
```

The method has built-in debug hooks implemented as bit-flags:

```
Names["O*`*DEBUG*"]
(*
{"Optimization`NonlinearInteriorPointDump`DEBUG", \
"Optimization`NonlinearInteriorPointDump`DEBUGcomplementary", \
"Optimization`NonlinearInteriorPointDump`DEBUGdirection", \
"Optimization`NonlinearInteriorPointDump`DEBUGfilter", \
"Optimization`NonlinearInteriorPointDump`DEBUGIterations", \
"Optimization`NonlinearInteriorPointDump`DEBUGLinearSolve", \
"Optimization`NonlinearInteriorPointDump`DEBUGMonitor", \
"Optimization`NonlinearInteriorPointDump`DEBUGNewton", \
"Optimization`NonlinearInteriorPointDump`DEBUGPenaltyIncrease", \
"Optimization`NonlinearInteriorPointDump`DEBUGpoints", \
"Optimization`NonlinearInteriorPointDump`DEBUGProblemdef", \
"Optimization`NonlinearInteriorPointDump`DEBUGrhs", \
"Optimization`NonlinearInteriorPointDump`DEBUGScaling", \
"Optimization`NonlinearInteriorPointDump`DEBUGstep", \
"Optimization`NonlinearInteriorPointDump`DEBUGsteplength"}
*)
```

They may be toggled on/off with comments as follows:

```
Block[{Optimization`NonlinearInteriorPointDump`DEBUG =
    (*2^Optimization`NonlinearInteriorPointDump`DEBUGProblemdef+*)
    2^Optimization`NonlinearInteriorPointDump`DEBUGIterations +
    2^Optimization`NonlinearInteriorPointDump`DEBUGstep +
    (*2^Optimization`NonlinearInteriorPointDump`DEBUGNewton+*)
    2^Optimization`NonlinearInteriorPointDump`DEBUGMonitor},
 FindMinimum[(x + 1)*(x - 1), x, Method -> "InteriorPoint"]
 ]
```

The code is complicated, but I suspect the method follows the standard IP algorithm.  Between the code and the debug, it might take just a morning to figure the outline of how it works.

Comment: Michael, do you happen to have an insight on how to make Gurobi work under *Mathematica* (please see [this Q](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/293732/89))? I have explored both the ``"GurobiLink`"`` and ``"Optimization`MethodFramework`"`` packages, with no success.