# How to set up the Gurobi optimizer?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, interoperability, licensing

How do I set up *Mathematica* to use the [commercial Gurobi optimizer](https://www.gurobi.com/)? *Mathematica* should be able to use it, as the `Method -> "Gurobi"` option exists for various optimization functions. I do have an academic license for Gurobi, and the Gurobi shell recognizes it correctly on my machine. However, *Mathematica* does not:

```
ConvexOptimization[x + 2 y, {x^2 + y^2 <= 1}, {x, y}, Method -> "Gurobi"]

ConvexOptimization::opmlicwf: The method Gurobi cannot be used since a valid
license could not be found. See get a license for Gurobi.
```

The *Mathematica* [workflow](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/GetALicenseForGurobi.html), to which the error message points, does not really help.

(Windows 10, 64bits, *Mathematica* 13.3, Gurobi 11.0, installed automatically to `C:\\gurobi1100`.)

Comment: In the \$UserBaseDirectory, I added to the file init.m in the Kernel directory the path to the GUROBI license file with AppendTo. For instance, I added the following line: AppendTo[$Path,"/YYY/home/XXX/local/gurobi/linux64/license"].

Comment: @HolgerI.Meinhardt The directory that holds the `gurobi.lic` file is already on my `$Path`.

Comment: I saw your post in chat. I used `ConexOptimization` with Gurobi in the past, but it was on an old laptop and I did not save the notebook. 
$$ $$
I cannot say this with 100% certainty, but if I remember correctly you need to use [GurobiLink](https://github.com/WolframResearch/GurobiLink) to interface between Mathematica and Gurobi software